# NSArray of NSArrays: Get value of index of contained array

Tags: ios, nsarray

I know I can get the value of objects with properties in an array like so:

```
[arrObjects valueForKey:@"objectKey];
```

and I can filter an array by a predicate

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectKey = foo"];
NSArray* arrShinyNewArray = [arrObjects filteredArrayWithPredicate:predicate];
```

but what if I had an array of arrays and wanted index 1 of the embedded arrays?

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least have the decency to leave a comment and explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct it yourself. There's no one-liner to do it:

```
NSMutableArray* secondItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:arrObjects.count];
for (NSArray* element in arrObjects)
    [secondItems addObject:element[1]];
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already made a category for it but was just wondering if I was duplicating work that Apple had already done.